Why does addEventListener not change the background color of the elements even though it is executed?
Why is it that when I move anotherSquare to square2 and click anotherSquare, the background color of square1 and square2 does not change even though console.log occurs?
const anotherSquare = document.querySelector(".anotherSquare");

anotherSquare.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Ok");
    const square1 = document.querySelector(".square1");
    const square2 = document.querySelector(".square2");
    square1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    square2.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    square2.addEventListener("click", () => {
        square1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        square2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        anotherSquare.remove();
        square2.appendChild(anotherSquare);
    })
})

I would like the background colors of square1 and square2 to change to green after moving anotherSquare to square2 and clicking anotherSquare

Please update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem you are trying to describe.

Try to use let instead of const. Const declares a readonly object. See the const information.

Nowhere in the code shown are any of those values being re-assigned though.  Is there some indication you're seeing that they're being re-assigned outside of the code shown?
